# Preventing screen resolution change

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

Is there any way to completely block all system applications from changing screen resolution? I have only one resolution in `xorg.conf` but games ( under Wine but also native ones) love to switch resolution to something small and unusable. After that I can't even use the `xrandr` to switch it back, I have to use `nvidia-settings` (I am using NVidia closed source drivers).

Comment: Maybe you can implement a workaround. Create a shortcut that uses nvidia properties to change to the resolution that you want, so when something changes the resolution, just type the shortcut and get it to the resolution you want.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/X11
touch xorg.conf
nano xorg.conf
```

then in the simple nano editor, write (or just paste) this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
        SubSection "Display"
          Modes "1280x800"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

*Change the Modes "1280x800" for your needs 
then save the file using Ctrl+O, then quit Ctrl+x.
Voila - logout and login again and resolution is fixed forever.

Thanks for the great wiki here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Hopefully it helps your question.